# Did Ayn Rand embrace critical realism?

Tags: realism, critical-thinking, ayn-rand

Critical realism in the sense that although a world exists outside our perception, we never fully grasp it.

Comment: Hard to say, since she's been dead for decades and so we cannot ask her.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3):

Ayn Rand thought that a world exists outside our perception and that we could create knowledge about that world. She also had wrote material saying that our knowledge is fallible, e.g. - on p. 78 of "Introduction to Objectivist Epistemology", Rand wrote:

> Man is neither infallible nor omniscient; if he were, a discipline such as epistemology—the theory of knowledge—would not be necessary nor possible: his knowledge would be automatic, unquestionable and total. But such is not man’s nature. Man is a being of volitional consciousness: beyond the level of percepts—a level inadequate to the cognitive requirements of his survival—man has to acquire knowledge by his own effort, which he may exercise or not, and by a process of reason, which he may apply correctly or not. Nature gives him no automatic guarantee of his mental efficacy; he is capable of error, of evasion, of psychological distortion. He needs a method of cognition, which he himself has to discover: he must discover how to use his rational faculty, how to validate his conclusions, how to distinguish truth from falsehood, how to set the criteria of what he may accept as knowledge. Two questions are involved in his every conclusion, conviction, decision, choice or claim: What do I know?—and: How do I know it?

For a more detailed discussion, read:

https://curi.us/2471-rand-popper-and-fallibility

Comment: Interesting, thank you. Is this entity of the external world attached to anything? Let's take for example a view of radical skepticism, the simulation theory/brain-in-the-tank theory. Would that change anything in the sense of her view "existence exists"?

Comment: Rand correctly regarded skepticism as false: see Chapter 9 of "Philosophy: Who Needs It".